# Is there a way to define a variable on a update mysql query?

Tags: mysql

I mean something like:

```
update table_name set field_1=if(date_add(data_field,interval 30 hour) >= now(),1,0), field_2=if(date_add(data_field,interval 30 hour) >= now(),1,0) where ...
```

well in this case i need to use date_add(data_field,interval 30 hour), two times, is there a way to store it in a variable or something like it? then i don't need to call it two times.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure:

```
set @mydate := date_add(data_field,interval 30 hour);

update table_name set
field_1=if(@mydate >= now(),1,0), 
field_2=if(@mydate >= now(),1,0)
where ...
```

Fyi, these are called [user defined variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html)

Comment: But the first `data_field` argument to the function call is presumably a column in the table...

Answer (score 2):

This is an unnecessary optimisation, as the query optimiser will recognise that the function call is deterministic, cache the result of calling it once and reuse that result in place of the second call.